# Use of に in 金色の血に染まる前に

Tags: particle-に

The translation I received was 'Before my blood was dyed golden'

How does the construct of No-verb + noun + に + verb works?

Does the に particle take the verb and puts it between the no adjective and noun 
so that it basically describes how the noun is affected by the adjective?

Basically 'blood that was dyed golden' instead of 'be dyed by golden blood'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be warned I am a non-native speaker, but here is what I found:

A quick google in a Japanese-Japanese dictionary (always better to consult than crappy english translations) says that one meaning of somaru means either "a color sticks to something" (to dye) or that something is turning a certain color, so the meaning is a bit more general than to dye. What you posted is a sentence fragment without a subject or topic, so I can assume that in this case the ni indicates that whatever the subject/topic is is being subsumed in color by golden blood. So in this case it indicates 'by' in English.

金色の血に - by golden blood
染まる前に - before subsumed (in color) / dyed by

Comment: If this is not correct, please comment as to why. I don't appreciate downvotes with not explanation.